# how to create MSMQ in pipeline component using Biztalk

Tags: c#, biztalk, msmq

I need to create a MSMQ dynamically inside the pipeline component. i am writing my **Execute** method of **IBaseMessage** in the following way.

```
public IBaseMessage Execute(IPipelineContext pContext, IBaseMessage pInMsg)
{
    IBaseMessagePart bodyPart = pInMsg.BodyPart;
    if (!MessageQueue.Exists(@".\private$\NewQueue.Queue"))
    {
        var messageQueue = MessageQueue.Create(@".\private$\NewQueue.Queue");
        messageQueue.SetPermissions("Everyone", MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl);
    }
    MessageQueue RequestQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\NewQueue");
    Message SendMsg = new Message();
    SendMsg.Body = bodyPart;
    RequestQueue.Send(SendMsg, "Siddharth");
    return pInMsg;
}
```

The message is going from receive port to send port but it is not creating any queue as i think my **Execute** method is not executing or i am not writing the correct code. Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well, before we answer, why do you want to do this?  Dynamically creating queues cannot be a good idea.  But most important, this is not the correct way to send Messages in BizTalk.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your execute method is actually being called, but then one of two things is hapenning:

1. The service account running your host instance does not have the required permissions to create the queue, or
2. The queue is being created but then the rest of your code does nothing because the queue is incorrectly addressed (missing the ".queue" suffix).

You can attach your debugger to a local btsntsvc.exe process and see if it's being called.